# Is there a sensible autocompletion widget available for SWT/JFace?

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, swt, jface

I wnat to have autocompletion for my application, but there are some pecularities I need to take care of.

The backing of my field is a list of objects, which may have several fields (lets say id and name). Autocompletion should work on on either one. After completion the field should contain the id, not the name, and it should be possible to input something different, namely an id which does not belong to an object of the given list.

Has somebody built something like that for SWT/JFace?

Answer (score 3):

Try looking at the `org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist` package, it may do what you want. More specifically, you can write your own `ContentProposalAdapter`, add a `IContentProposalListener`, and attach it to the modify event of a `Text` widget, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

I used [SWT Add-ons](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swtaddons/) for auto-complete text fields. They're not perfect, but worked for me

Comment: I use it too. Gets the job done (had to change some code to get the desired effect)